# How to change values inside a modal in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, bootstrap-modal

I am having trouble inserting values from a form into a modal. I have this in my 'customer_accounts.coffee' file:

```
jQuery -> 
  $('#submitBtn').click (evt) ->
    $("#fname").html $('#customer_account_fname').val()
```

and the modal is inside the partial '_form.html.erb' which is rendered in 'new_customer_account.html.erb'.

Inside the modal's body is:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure you want to submit the following details?
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
             <th>First Name</th>
             <td id="fname">abc</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? My guess is that the problem lies here:

```
$("#fname")**.html** $('#customer_account_fname').val()
```

Comment: `$("#fname")**.html** $('#customer_account_fname').val()`? $("#fname").html($('#customer_account_fname').val())

Comment: `$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() { $("#fname").html($('#customer_account_fname').val()); });`

Comment: Thank you for looking. I found the solution and its one that would not have been apparent from the question I posted. The problem was that I had another element within the body with the same id for testing purposes, which probably meant that jquery found it first, did its job then quit. Rookie mistake!